# How to convert .dbc to .csv without loss of information?

Tags: database, csv, foxpro, file-conversion

I have a little utility that converts .dbc files to .csv files, trouble is, somewhere in the conversion some data is lost/destroyed/whatever. I input a.dbc into converter, it produces a.csv. I delete a.dbc,and then run a.csv back through the converter, and I come back with a "slightly" different .dbc file then I had started with.

Does anyone know any better way of converting these files? Without loss of information..

I open both files in HexCMP (compares two hex files, show's you the differences) and the differences are totally random through out the file.

Comment: Can you shed some light on what app uses .dbc files ?

Comment: http://extension.informer.com/dbc/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this is nothing more than a buggy utility.

If you convert the same .dbc file to a .csv file twice in a row, do you get the exact same .csv file?  If you run the .csv through twice do you get the same .dbc file out both times?  That would at least tell you which side of the conversion the bugs are in.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to FoxPro to export the file as a CSV directly from FoxPro without using the utility? That would allow you to compare the CSV file created from FoxPro versus your utility to try and narrow down where the problem is.